# Изменение фона колеcом мыши. События JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Я отчасти новичок в программировании, и я пытаюсь изучить новые методы и способы...
Можете ли вы показать, как создать на странице элемент с некоторым фоном, оттенок цвета которого изменяется при "вертикальном" прокручивании колеса мыши, а яркость - "горизонтальном" прокручивании (WheelEvent). Рекомендуется устанавливать цвет в HSL формате.
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: у меня нет горизонтального колеса на мышке

Comment: нужно сделать сам элемент с некоторым фоном по размерам больше, чем монитор. Что-бы появилась двигающая полоса снизу для прокручивания, скажем так.

Comment: я обновил ответ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вертикальный скролл меняет `saturation`

горизонтальный - `lightness`

```js
let m = 25, a = 60, s = m, l = m, d = document.documentElement;

window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) { 
  s = m + a * d.scrollTop / (d.scrollHeight - d.clientHeight);
  l = m + a * d.scrollLeft / (d.scrollWidth - d.clientWidth);
  updateColor();
});

function updateColor() {
  document.querySelector('#square').style.backgroundColor = `hsl(150,${s}%,${l}%)`
};

updateColor();
```

```html
<body style="margin:0">
<div id="square" style="width:1500px; height:1500px;"></div>
</body>
```